# how to read words from a file using shell script

Tags: shell

i have a file `/ws/$1-rcd/temp.txt` which has only one line as follows

```
198|/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/...
```

i have a script to get the value repository/open_source/commons_collections and 3_2_2 by reading the file and looping through it using for loop

i have my code as follows

```
grep -n "$4" /ws/$1-rcd/raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " " -f1,2 | sed -e 's/\:element/|/g' | sed -e 's/ //g' > /ws/$1-rcd/temp.txt
    for i in `cat /ws/$1-rcd/temp.txt`
    do
    line=`echo $i | cut -d"|" -f1`
    path=`echo $i | cut -d"|" -f2`
    whoami
    directory_temp=`echo $path | awk -F "/" '{ print $(NF-2)}'`
    if [ "$directory_temp" == "$4" ]
    then
    OLD_VERSION=`sed -n "${line}p" /ws/$1-rcd/raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d      " " -f2 | awk -F "/" '{ print $(NF-1)}'`
    total_fields=`sed -n "${line}p" /ws/$1-rcd/raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " " -f2 | awk -F "/" '{ print NF }'`
    dir_path=`expr ${total_fields} - 2`

    loc=`sed -n "${line}p" /ws/$1-rcd/raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " "        -f2     | cut         -d"/" -f1-"${dir_path}"`

    location=`echo $loc | cut -d"/" -f4,5,6`
    fi
    done
```

but when i run this code it gives me an error as

> -bash: line 45: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
>   -bash: line 45:`for i in 198|/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/...'

can anyone please suggest what am i doing wrong

Comment: It's better to ask what you are doing right, and the answer is *not much*. Start with the [bash-faq](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) first item and take it from there. Good luck,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate through each line of a file, use while loop like below

```
while read -r line ;do
  echo $line
done <file.txt
```

so, your code can be rewritten as

```
grep -n "$4" /ws/$1-rcd/raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " " -f1,2 | sed -e 's/\:element/|/g' | sed -e 's/ //g' > /ws/$1-rcd/temp.txt
while read i ;  do
    line=`echo $i | cut -d"|" -f1`
    path=`echo $i | cut -d"|" -f2`
    whoami
    directory_temp=`echo $path | awk -F "/" '{ print $(NF-2)}'`
    if [ "$directory_temp" == "$4" ]
    then
    OLD_VERSION=`sed -n "${line}p" /ws/$1-rcd/raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d      " " -f2 | awk -F "/" '{ print $(NF-1)}'`
    total_fields=`sed -n "${line}p" /ws/$1-rcd/raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " " -f2 | awk -F "/" '{ print NF }'`
    dir_path=`expr ${total_fields} - 2`

    loc=`sed -n "${line}p" /ws/$1-rcd/raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " "        -f2     | cut         -d"/" -f1-"${dir_path}"`

    location=`echo $loc | cut -d"/" -f4,5,6`
    fi
done < /ws/$1-rcd/temp.txt
```

Comment: but when i run this code it gives me an error as this                                        -bash: line 352: syntax error near unexpected    token `in'
    -bash: line 352: `in'

Comment: @priyanka, above code has only 17 lines. You must be having some additional lines of code. Hence, I can debug by using a line number. Can you check in your text editor. what does line 352 pointing to ?

Comment: ,line 352 is pointing to the last line of the code,my code only has the above lines except that i have a su command in the beginning of the code and an EOF at the end as in                                                                            su - $1 << EOF    <code> EOF .here $1 is my user id

Comment: @priyanka, So, in your text editor line 352 =`done < /ws/$1-rcd/temp.txt` ??, If so, please provide the first argument given to this script.

Comment: @Raju....i have provided the first argument                                                                                                         #!/bin/bash
    su - $1 << EOF
    user_id=$1
    branch=$2
    task_name=$3
    directory=$4
    <...code..>                                                                                                        EOF
    echo "OUT"
so the last line is echo "OUT"

Comment: @priyanka, lets continue our discussion in this chat room --> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104600/rajusechatroom

Comment: @Raju..this script works without su command ,but i want to run this script as a specific user..the script is failing if i use su - user_id

Answer (score 0):

You may be better served relying on parameter expansion and substring removal. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=$(<dat/lline.txt)       ## read file into a
a=${a##*ccm_tpl/}         ## remove from left to ccm_tpl/
num=${a##*collections/}   ## remove from left to collections/
num=${num%%/*}            ## remove from right to /
a=${a%%${num}*}           ## remove from right to $num
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/lline.txt
198|/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/..
```

**Output**

```
$ sh getvals.sh

 a   : repository/open_source/commons_collections/
 num : 3_2_2
```

If you need to trim in some other way, just let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: @David...but here we are hard coding the values ryt.will this method work if i hve 2 lines in my file which i want to read                                               as in 198|/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/.. and 198|/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections_user/3_2_2/..

Comment: In that case you would use a loop `while read -r a; do <same code>; done <filename`.